# How to read key and value from xml file using delimiters in java?

Tags: java, xml

I want to read the following xml `<LINE>` tag using java. Could you please help with this? Thanks in advance.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<LINE>002:OR,004:0001,002:01,002:01,007:SCEM_02,000:,007:590,000,002:KG,002:PC;/</LINE>
```

Comment: Read it how? If that's all there is, just read the line from the file.

Answer (score 2):

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public String extractLine(String xmlSource) {
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("<LINE>(.*?)</LINE>");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(xmlSource);
    boolean found = m.find();
    if (!found)
        return null;
    return m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Never use regular expressions to parse XML, except possibly for code that you intend to run once and then throw away. This code will fail, for example, if there is a space before the ">" in the start tag. Downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

Situation specific solution would be :

```
String str = "<LINE>002:OR,004:0001,002:01,002:01,007:SCEM_02,000:,007:590,000,002:KG,002:PC;/</LINE> ";
str = str.substring((str.indexOf(">")+1),str.lastIndexOf("<"));
System.out.println(str);
```